# Adding custom html email signature in web Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, signature, email-signature

So I have seen some tutorials (there are not many on this topic) on how to add custom html email signature in outlook (web). So I go to settings, and then compose and reply, and there i should inspect the page and paste there HTML code. here is my code:
https://codepen.io/sonjaknezevic/pen/MWxwjza

`

```
    <div class="subcontainer">
        <div class="subcontainer-item">
            <span class="name">John Doe</span>
            <span class="role">Founder &amp; CEO</span>
        </div>
        <div class="subcontainer-item">
            <span class="contact">Email: john@company.com</span>
            <span class="contact">Mob: +300 00 000 000</span>
            <span class="contact">Website: <a class="link"  href="#">company.com</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Which looks like this when i open it in browser [image: html code in browser]

Now I have copied and pasted code where I should in the inspect part, and saved the signature, but when I try to send an email it doesn't look as it should, here is also the image of how it looks when I want to send an email: [image: email signature when sending email]

I have found other way around tho but it is not the solution i quite need i had to compromise some looks but this way it works. I have made a table template in Microsoft Word and filled it with what i need, but I need poppins font family and so on...

I would really appreciate it if someone could help! Also one more question, is there a way to make this dynamic? Since it is for company and I would have manually to go to every employee to set this signature up in web outlook for their names and so on.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 2):

Because most of the email clients are using the old version of the HTML and CSS rendering technique, so that you have to use the `HTML table` as layout in emails. Please find the below link to how you can achieve that step by step:
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770a

Comment: okay i have managed to do it with table, but after doing some research i see that most email clients do not handle custom fonts, and I need to use Poppins. I assume there is no way to import this font, as I can see the only solution would be like an image of this signature with that font

Comment: @sonj4 yes, you are right. You can only use some default fonts like `Arial` etc.